# How to make jsp page redirect to home page after expired?

Tags: jsp

I have developed an web application using JSP and deployed in tomcat server.
In that, if the user remains idle in the application for more than 5 min then their session should expire.but I don't know how to redirect the user to the login page/home page  after session timeout.
I used the following code to make the session expire

`<%session.setMaxInactiveInterval(300);%>`

Please give me some ideas to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Raj

Comment: How do you handle a login? The default form-based login mechanism does this for you: when accessing a login-protected page without being logged in, it redirects to the login page.

Comment: Yes after the session expiring, when the user access secured page, the user should be automatically redirected to login page.

Comment: @Raj: this doesn't answer my question. How do you handle a login? Are you using a standard JEE mechanism, or are you rolling your own mechanism? What's thr principle of the custom mechanism then?

Comment: if any one wants to down vote please give me the reason , don't simply down vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a filter and then check for this and redirect

```
if(session != null && !session.isNew())
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
else
    response.sendRedirect("/myhomepage.jsp");
```